# In virtual mode my datagridview is slagging when loading multiple time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, virtual

I am using virtual mode with caching to load my datagridview in my WinForms application, using the same code available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/virtual-mode-with-just-in-time-data-loading-in-the-datagrid)

Changed the `SupplyData` function to be able to search data like below

```
public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        // Store the name of the ID column. This column must contain unique 
        // values so the SQL below will work properly.
        columnToSortBy = this.Columns[0].ColumnName;

        //if (!this.Columns[columnToSortBy].Unique)
        //{
        //    throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
        //        "Column {0} must contain unique values.", columnToSortBy));
        //}

        // Retrieve the specified number of rows from the database, starting
        // with the row specified by the lowerPageBoundary parameter.
        command.CommandText = "Select CPNum, strftime('%d-%m-%Y', CPEdtDate) AS CPEdtDate From " + tableName + " WHERE CPNum LIKE '%" + search + "%' AND " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
            tableName + " WHERE CPNum LIKE '%" + search + "%' Order By " + columnToSortBy + " LIMIT " + lowerPageBoundary + ") Order By " + columnToSortBy + " LIMIT " + rowsPerPage;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
```

When reloading grid I am using following code

```
DataRetriever retriever =
            new DataRetriever(connectionString, table, search);
        memoryCache = new Cache(retriever, 16);
        foreach (DataColumn column in retriever.Columns)
        {
            if (!masterChartGrid.Columns.Contains(column.ColumnName))
            {
                masterChartGrid.Columns.Add(
                        column.ColumnName, "Edition Date");
            }
        }
        masterChartGrid.Rows.Clear();
        this.masterChartGrid.RowCount = retriever.RowCount;
```

it works fine for searching data. But when I try to reset the search and reload table again the application becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I added DataGridView programmatically from `.cs` file.

`private DataGridView masterChartGrid = new DataGridView();`